# Android AsyncAPI ahax query with custom http headers

Tags: android, ajax, http, header, aquery

How can I add this http header

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

to this ajax query?

```
 public void asyncJson(){

    //perform a Google search in just a few lines of code

    String url = "http://www.mysite.com/Services/GetJson";

    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("nNumResults", "100");                                                  

    aq.ajax(url, params, JSONObject.class, new AjaxCallback<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void callback(String url, JSONObject json, AjaxStatus status) {

            if(json != null){

                //successful ajax call, show status code and json content
                Toast.makeText(aq.getContext(), status.getCode() + ":" + json.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();            
            }else{                    
                //ajax error, show error code
                Toast.makeText(aq.getContext(), "Error:" + status.getCode(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });

 } // asyncJson
```

Comment: Is the `; charset=utf-8`-part really needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not got a huge amount of experience with android-query but this looks like this example from their [async API documentation](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/AsyncAPI#Http_Headers) should do the trick;

```
String url = "http://www.mysite.com/Services/GetJson";

AjaxCallback<JSONObject> cb = new AjaxCallback<JSONObject>();        
cb.url(url).type(JSONObject.class).weakHandler(this, "jsonCb");

cb.header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
cb.param("nNumResults", "100");

aq.ajax(cb);
```

Note that when setting params you can also use a Map;

```
Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
cb.params(params);
```

Watchout for the [gotcha](http://android-query.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/androidquery/callback/AbstractAjaxCallback.html#param%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) when working with the param method. It will default the "Content-Type" header for you if you haven't already set it.

You should then get back a response to `this.jsonCb(String url, JSONObject jsonObject, AjaxStatus status)`.

Comment: thanks, but this sample does not have parameters for the http post, the json is not returned if I don't add parameters to http post.

Comment: I've added a note about setting the parameters.

Comment: I get this error...Description Resource Path Location Type
The method type(Class<JSONObject>) in the type AbstractAjaxCallback<JSONObject,AjaxCallback<JSONObject>> is not applicable for the arguments (Class<String>) MainActivity.java /myapp/src/com/ultimate/millionquotes line 92 Java Problem

Comment: My mistake, lifted the example from the Android Query docs. That should be `cb.url(url).type(JSONObject.class)`. I've corrected the example.

Comment: Thank you very much! and I wish you a Merry Christmas!